# Re-deploy app but selectively preserve old data on device

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment, device

For testing purposes, I need to periodically deploy new builds of my iOS app to the device which has old data in its document folder. I'd like to be able to selectively update part of the data and control keep-new or keep-old behaviour for any files in the document folder.

Basically, the tooling support I want is to update only the data that changed when deploying to device. For example whatever in the dev-machine's Xcode project resource folder that are newer or different from their counterparts (files of the same names) on the device (by date, size, etc.) get transferred and their counterparts on the device get overwritten by those. Everything else is ignored.

An ideal scenario would be: When I hit BuildAndRun in Xcode, Xcode will figure out what data to transfer-and-overwrite-device-files and what not to based on some custom rules.

Is is possible to achieve this with Xcode?

**UPDATE**
I edited the above text to make it clear that I don't want to add app logic for data versioning. I want this to happen in my build-and-test pipeline (Xcode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, this is pretty simple.  Everything that XCode sends goes in the resource bundle.  If you update it on the device, you have to move it to the documents directory, as the resource bundle is write only.

Any resources that you might be updating on the device already need 'does document version exist' kind of logic, the only change you have is to maybe add some modification date stuff.

You do have the option in the run scheme to upload application data to the sandbox directory.

Here is a good starting point:-
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-devices_organizer/articles/copy_app_data_to_sandbox.html

In essence, you can download data from a device in the device manager and create an xcdata package.  Edit this to contain just the stuff you want to upload.

You can then either upload this manually or specify it in the Edit Scheme dialog ( under options), so it gets uploaded every time you run the scheme.

[image: Edit Scheme Dialog]

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. This looks like almost what I want. One question remains: Can the data downloading/uploading be automated, e.g., using xcode command line toolchains? Thanks!

Comment: At deployment time, no, at run time, yes, I'll edit the answer to make this clear.

Comment: Thank you again Gordon. Unfortunately I can't seem to see any app data under that combo box. So I started a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618540/ios-how-to-specify-application-data-package-in-xcode-schemes

Comment: I don't see how you're going to do custom rules. I have a feeling that XCode users rsync to copy the package across to the device in development mode, but I'm not sure about this. If you're custom rules are 'Copy these, but not these', then just put the ones you need to copy in the app data package, and leave the others out. I'm not an expert on this TBH, I expected to write a far shorter answer, but in my quick tour of the documentation, I came across this app data stuff.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the 'correct answer', and I'll go and answer the other question for extra smiles.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way I see to do it is to encode a version number in the files, and the ones you need to update, you increase the version number on them in your code, so when it runs and encounters a file that has a lesser version number, it deletes or ignores it

Comment: So do you mean I just keep transferring data into the doc folder, and handle this version control in my app ObjC code?

Comment: @kakyo as you create the files, you could add a header to the file, or just to the file name itself

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get it. My files have headers, but their names cannot change (the app relies on the names). Do you mean that my app code really needs to look at the headers to tell the version? Ideally what I want is when I hit BuildAndRun in Xcode, Xcode will figure out what data to transfer-and-overwrite-device-files and what not to based on some custom rules.