# How to specify application data package in Xcode Schemes?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'd like to specify an application data package using Xcode schemes so that I can customize and deploy to the device during testing. However, by default, the Scheme | Option | Application Data combo box has no items in it.

I guess I would need to create the package and add it to my xcodeproj. But I can't find any documentation about this, not even in the bulky book Xcode4 Unleashed. I also tried to build for Archive first. But after that still "No Data" under the Option page.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Easiest way I know is to go to the Organiser  (apple shift 2), and then find a connected device.

Go to applications and select the application you need app data for and hit download.  This is going to dump some of the sandbox data into a package on your dev machine.

To use this in the scheme, you just need to add this to your project, and then it will show up in the drop down.

As far as I can see, there isn't a way to choose what data to put in the xcappdata file, but since it is a package, you can open it in the finder ( show package contents) and get rid of anything you don't want.

Hope this helps